# Simple Modulo Operations

Tags: c++, int, division, modulo

So I am learning C++, and in one of the books I'm reading, there is an example for finding GCF (greatest common factor). The function is as follows:

```
int gcf(int a, int b) {
    if(b == 0) {
        return a;
    }
    else {
        return gcf(b, a%b);
    }
}
```

What I don't understand is that if I put in 15 and 5 for example, then

```
a = 15
b = 5
b is not 0 so then the else statement executes
(5, 15%5 = 0) so since b is now 0 it returns, a, which is 5.
```

That makes sense, but if I reverse the numbers, why/how do I get the same answer?

```
a = 5
b = 15
b is not 0 so then the else statement executes
(15, 5%15) but 5%15 is .3 or 1/3, but in C++, 5%15 returns 5.
```

I don't understand where 5 comes from, if anything, since it's an integer, I thought it maybe return 0 but it doesn't return 15, so it can't be.

Comment: Since when did `5%15 = 1/3`? Are you confusing division with modulus?

Comment: its the remainder of 5/15 would be 0 with a remainder of 5

Comment: I think I was confusing division with modulus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing is integer calculation - no floating points or fractions involved.

`5 % 15` is actually the remainder you get after dividing 5 by 15, and that is, of course, 5 (the quotient would be 0).

```
15 |  5 | 0   <-- this is the first call gcf(5, 15)
      0
     ---
      5 | 15 | 3  <-- this is the first recursive call gcf(15, 5)
          15
         ---
           0 |  5 |   <-- this is the second recursive call gcf(5, 0), returns 5
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. The example you gave was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Modulo operator is different from division,usually when we divide the return value is a quotient but when you use modulo operator return value is its reminder.
so in your case when

**

> a=5 and b = 15, a%b the return value of this was 0 ,

**

that is the reason why it returned 5. check the following links for greater clarity on modulo operator
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/modulus.html

Comment: Thanks, I found the websites really useful.

Answer (score 0):

In integer division, 5/15 = 0. Since `5%15` is the remainder, it needs to be 5. C and C++ mandate that for any `a` and `b`, `a/b*b + a%b = a`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested, the piece of code you have written there is called Euclid's Algorithm which is based upon Euclid's Lemma (big surprise there). Although I heard from a professor that some people might refer to different formulations of Euclid's Lemma. My Higher Algebra book particularly refers to it as "Equal gcd's".
It states:

**Let a, b, q, and c be integers with a=qb+c. Then gcd(a,b)=gcd(b,c)**

gcd(a,b) refers to the greatest common divisor of a and b.
This seems to be precisely what you are doing in your program.

Any integer a can be written as the qb+c for any b. This means that a is a product qb plus some remainder c. The remainder here is what you are calculating when you use the % operator. If we let a = 12 and b = 5 then can write 12=5q+c. Let q be 2. Then our remainder c is 2. Perhaps these things are elementary but hopefully this is nice background to supplement your book's explanation.